# Automapper Ignore default value for dateTime

Tags: automapper

I want a dynamic ignore for dateTime default value `{1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM}`
I used this code for nullable values

```
.ForMember(d => d.CreatedBy, opt => opt.Condition(s => !s.IsSourceValueNull))
```

but how may I do it for dateTime value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.CreatedOn,
           opt => opt.Condition(src => src.CreatedOn != default(DateTime)))
```